# Error undefined local variable or method `action_name' in ruby

Tags: ruby, parameters, arguments

i have two methods in base class, method_1 does perform_async with some *args by calling the worker and after job is done it will call method_2, how to pass same args to method_2?

```
def self.method_1(action_name, *args)
   perform_async(action_name,args)
   method_2
end

def self.method_2
   some action here
   method_1(action_name, args)
   handle exception here
end
```

getting error undefined local variable or method `action_name' in line number 3 of method 2.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you are asking. If  ``method_1`` simply calls ``method_2`` as shown, why not simply change ``method_2`` to take the same parameters as ``method_1`` and pass them directly? Also, that snippet is a recipe for an infinite loop, since the methods call each other.

Comment: As an aside, you mention that you want ``method_1`` to call ``method_2`` 'after the job is done'. But because you are using``.perform_async()``, ``method_2`` will be called immediately after the job is enqueued, which is not the same thing as when the job is done.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you're going for, what about using an instance variable to store the splat parameter arguments?

```
def self.method_1(action_name, *args)
   @args = args
   perform_async(action_name, args)
   method_2
end

def self.method_2
   some action here
   method_1(action_name, @args)
   handle exception here
end
```